# How to move active window to another display in XFCE

Tags: shortcut-keys, display, xfce

I use a multi display workspace, I would like to have keyboard shortcut for moving an active window to another display (I don't mean workspaces). How can I achieve this in XFCE? In Unity, I was using Compiz with predefined keyboard shortcuts.

[image: my workspace]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

XFCE does not have a built-in command that allows you to move a window to another monitor, however there is [the movescreen Python script](https://github.com/calandoa/movescreen) by [calandoa](https://askubuntu.com/users/263937/calandoa) that can do that.

The script is used as:

```
movescreen.py [-r] <up|down|left|right|prev|next|fit> [active|a] [mouse|m] [win_id]
```

- First, make sure the script's dependencies are satisfied:

  ```
  sudo apt install python xrandr xwininfo wmctrl xdotool
  ```
- Download the script and move it to the folder that you want, for example `~/scripts/` (I am assuming this as the script's folder for the next steps, you may, however, use whatever you want).
- Give executable rights to the script:

  ```
  chmod u+x ~/scripts/movescreen.py
  ```
- Open *Keyboard* and select the *Application Shortcuts* tab.
- Click the *Add* button at the bottom left.
- In the *Command* pop-up window enter the command to move the window, using the **absolute path** to the script. For example, to move the window to the monitor left, enter:

  ```
  /home/<your_username>/scripts/movescreen.py left
  ```

  where `<your_username>` is, well, your username.
- Press *OK* and assign the shortcut you want, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.
- Repeat the steps for all other directions.

The script is not perfect, but works reasonably well. Also, being built in Python means that it is relatively easy to tweak it to your needs.

Comment: the tool is not perfect (if only a few pixels of a window overlap to another monitor, neither left nor right will work). but it's enough until my distro supports 4.17.2 ;)

Answer (score 8):

Since Xfce4 4.17.2 (2022 Dec) there's a proper way to do it: *Window Manager* -> *Keyboard* tab:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Managed to do it as follows:

1. Install `xdotool` using:

   ```
   apt install xdotool
   ```
2. Then run:

   ```
   xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry
   ```

   with output:

   ```
   Window 69206023
     Position: 2201,251 (screen: 0)
     Geometry: 774x568
   ```
3. Moving to right command:

   ```
   xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 2201 251 windowsize 774 568
   ```
4. Finally just put the following in `/usr/bin/moveright` script and bind it on a keyboard shortcut:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 2201 251 windowsize 774 568
   ```

Comment: This is a very good & simple solution. If I may add something, there's no need to specify a `windowsize XX XX` parameter in the `xdotool` command. That way, you can use it with arbitrary windows without changing their size.